Excel create shifts based on timestamps
I need a formula that returns shifts (morning, lunch etc) and days of the week based on timestamps :
Morning: 5AM to 11AM
Lunch:11AM to 1PM
Afternoon:1PM to 5PM
Dinner:5PM to 10PM
Late night:10PM to 5AM
Currently my timestamps look like this "12/12/2022 19:21:23"
I have tried everything from if to xlookup and still doesn't work. Can you please put me in the right direction?
I have separated days of the week from the timestamp with
=TEXT(C3,"dddd")
and the hour with
=HOUR(C3)&":"&MINUTE(C3)

Create a list with all possible options (say in range AA1:AC6):


EDIT: very important part, you need to do the time table as follow:

Otherwise you will get errors on late night shift. (You can start with 5:00 in cell AB2, the rest needs to be formula.)
End edit

Use =TEXT(C3,"dddd") to extract the day (you already got this right);
Use =TEXT(C3,"h:mm")*1 to extract the timestamp (in hour and minute), in numerical value(!);
Using this formula you can extract which shift the time stamps falls in between:
=XLOOKUP(1,(D3>=AB2:AB6)*(D3<=AC2:AC6),AA2:AA6,IF(D3<AB2,AA6,"error"))
With D3 being the cell with your timestamp. Adjust ranges as you use them.


thank you this work but i just realized that i was counting duplicate rows. How can I add on to this formula to only count UNIQUE rows located in column A (different column) than my criterias

Column A is the list of all your dates-times?

If you use Excel 2019 or later then IFS is avail.
=IFS(HOUR(C3)>=22,"Late night",HOUR(C3)>=19,"Diner",HOUR(C3)>=13,"Afternoon",HOUR(C3)>=11, "Lunch",HOUR(C3)>=5,"Morning",TRUE,"Late night")
The formula takes the hour of the timestamp and look for the corresponding shift.

I would extract the time part of the timestamp using Mod then use the 'exact match or next smaller item' option of Xlookup to find the required part of the day:
=XLOOKUP(MOD(A2,1),D$2:D$7,E$2:E$7,,-1)


Note that 'Late night' appears twice in the table.

For practicing XLOOKUP, using Tom's data (Excel 2021 and up), enter in the first cell (no need to fill-down):
=LET(
    last_cell, XLOOKUP(TRUE, $A:$A <> "", $A:$A, , , -1),
    shift_start, $A$1:last_cell,
    shifts, {"Morning", "Lunch", "Afternoon", "Dinner", "Late night"},
    starts, {5, 11, 13, 17, 22},
    IF(
        ISBLANK(shift_start),
        "",
        XLOOKUP(HOUR(shift_start), starts, shifts, "Late night", -1, 2)
    )
)


